# Crear URL Dinámica en un template Django

Tags: django, python-3.7, django-urls

Estoy tratando de crear una url "**dinámica**" en un template con django.
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<a href="{% url 'MostrarDet' IdProd='{{ dsProd.IdProd }}' IdGrupo='{{ Grupo.1 }}' %}">{{ Grupo.2 }}</a>
```

Pero el resultado de esto es:

```
<a href="/mostrardet/%7B%7B%20dsProd.IdProd%20%7D%7D/%7B%7B%20Grupo.1%20%7D%7D">Grupo DETALLE</a>
```

Y lo que necesito que genere es:

```
<a href="/mostrardet/PROD001/DET">Grupo DETALLE</a>
```

Qué estoy haciendo mal...???
Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Debería ser así: `{% url 'MostrarDet' IdProd=dsProd.IdProd IdGrupo=Grupo.1 %}`

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
<a href="{% url 'MostrarDet' dsProd.IdProd Grupo.1 %}">{{ Grupo.2 }}</a>
```

MostrarDet debe estar configurado para recibir 2 parámetros en IdProd e IdGrupo